# How to access non defined database in Django?

Tags: django, database

I have a problem with my application. I don't know how to access non defined database in Django. Where in my application user creates his own database if they needed, but Django cannot support database which is not defined. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Save the database name in session. 
Then using python connector for connecting to the database whenever needed.
For an example for postgres connection

```
psycopg2.connect(dbname=constants.POSTGRES_DB_NAME, user=constants.POSTGRES_USER,
                                host=constants.POSTGRES_DB_HOST, password=constants.POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD,
                                port=constants.POSTGRES_DB_PORT)
```